# Increase cryptswap size

Tags: gparted, swap

My cryptswap is now 4gb. I upgraded my RAM and I'd like to increase the swap accordingly to approx 8GB.

So far, I've reduced the size of my main sda1 partition with GParted by 4gb and I'm left with 4gb of unallocated space.

[image]

Next, I wanted to increase the swapsize of sda2 but GParted returns this error:

> GParted 0.12.1 --enable-libparted-dmraid
>
> Libparted 2.3
>
> Move /dev/sda2 to the left and grow it from 3.88 GiB to 7.79 GiB  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
>
> calibrate /dev/sda2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
>
> path: /dev/sda2
>   start: 616,994,814
>   end: 625,141,759
>   size 8,146,946 (3.88 GiB)
>   move partition to the left and grow it from 3.88 GiB to 7.79 GiB  00:00:00    ( ERROR )
>
> old start: 616,994,814
>   old end: 
>   old size: 8,146,946 (3.88 GiB)
>   requested start: 608,800,768
>   requested end: 625,139,711
>   requested size: 16,338,944 (7.79 GiB)
>   libparted messages    ( INFO )
>
> Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
>   Can't have overlapping partitions.

I don't understand the statement

> Can't have overlapping partitions.

The partitions do not overlap.

The output of `swapon -s` returns

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1                  partition   4073468 0   -1
```

I guess the issue I encountered with GParted is related to cryptswap?

Comment: You probably have to turn off swap and unmount the mapper volume before you can resize.  If you're using lvm, it takes more steps as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have encountered the following problem:

[Bug 678831 - Partition End Overlap when Resizing Extended Partition](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678831)

This bug was fixed in GParted 0.13.0.

Since many problems have been fixed since the 0.12.1 release of GParted, would you be able to try the latest release (currently 0.16.1)?

An easy way to do this is by booting from media containing [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).

Curtis

Comment: Thank you Curtis. This must have been the bug - resizing worked well with GParted 0.16.1. sda2 is now 8 gb but the encrypted swap sda5 is still 4GB. Any idea how to increase the cryptswap?

Answer (score 2):

ok, with Curtis' help it worked.

GParted 0.12.1 has a bug - resizing worked with 0.16.1

Then I did following steps:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo cryptsetup remove /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
sudo mkswap /dev/sda5 8168400
```

now, I have an unencrypted swap.
To encrypt it, swap needs to be turned on

```
sudo swapon /dev/sda5
```

and encrypted:

```
sudo ecryptfs-setup-swap
```

That's it.